# Communicating with Linux scripts from php web

Tags: java, php, linux, sockets, communication

I'm building a web application that helps people improve their English pronunciation for some words. The website displays a sentence for the user, and he/she speaks it and then press "Results" button. The web application then sends two files to the server: .txt and .wav files.

The server (which is Linux (Ubuntu)) should take the files, and do some analysis and calculations, and then print out the results on a file called "Results.txt". Then the web application (which is php based) should read the results from the file and displays them to the user.

The problem is: I'm not sure what is best to do the communication between the web application and the Linux server. Till now, I succeeded in writing the .txt and .wav files on the server. And I can build a Linux script that takes these two files and do the required calculations. What I'm facing is that: I don't know how to properly and effectively start the script. And more importantly: when the script is done, how to know that I can safely read the results from the "Results.txt" file? I need a synchronization tool or method.

I asked some guys, and they told me to use a java application on the server side, but I not sure how to do it!

Any help, Please?? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can do it with PHP. Using the shell_exec() method you can run commands your Linux scripts and also read the output. Ex:

> $output = shell_exec("ls -l > outputFile.txt");

will write the current directory listing to a file called outputFile.txt

Second, you can also do the same using Java. Use:

> Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -l").waitfor();

Not using the waitfor() in the end will cause asynchronous execution of your shell script. You can also read the stdout and stderr streams of your Linux script using

> Process.getInputStream()

and

> Process.getErrorStream()

methods respectively. Hope that helps.